# Значение выражения "Счастья не взбалтывать"

Tags: фразеология

Контекст из рассказа "жизнеописание одной мысли" С. Кржижановского:

Моральный же закон, приплюснутый теменем Штумпа, не нуждался уже в непрактичных и легко бьющихся каменных скрижалях: он мог с удобством уместиться и на   назидательной жестяной доске, украшающей аллеи общественных садов: "Цветов не рвать", "Травы не топтать". Добавлялось: "Чужих жен не любить", "В душу не плевать", "Счастья не взбалтывать" и еще две-три максимы. Кстати: все древние "не" были подперты "но". На всякий случай.

"Счастья не взбалтывать" — устойчивое словосочетание ли это? Как перевести его?

Answer (score 1):

***Смешать, но не взбалтывать.***

Это рецепт идеального коктейля Джеймса Бонда. 
 https://artemspec.livejournal.com/504345.html

Далее выражению стали придавать **обобщенное значение**, например: Книга "***Смешать, но не взбалтывать***: Рецепты организации мероприятий".

https://itexts.net/avtor-aleksandr-shumovich/213742-smeshat-no-ne-vzbaltyvat-recepty-organizacii-meropriyatiy-aleksandr-shumovich/read/page-1.html

В том числе **относительно счастья**:

Из рецензии на книгу Маши Трауб «Миллиграммы счастья»

«Обычная жизнь, замешанная на валерьянке, пустырнике, кофе, вине, виски, иногда в непозволительных пропорциях. ***Смешать, но не взбалтывать.*** Счастье — оно в миллиграммах.»

Вероятно, смысл в том, что даже в сложном предмете желательно **различать его составляющие  части**, каждая из которых важна сама по себе.

Comment: Интересно, но не совсем отвечает на вопрос, так как не стыкуется по времени. [Ян Флеминг](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Fleming) написал свой первый роман про Бонда в 1952 (Казино "Рояль"), [С. Кржижановский](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кржижановский,_Сигизмунд_Доминикович) умер в 1950-м.